# What are the differences between GWAS and QTL mapping?

Tags: genomics, gwas

What are the differences between the two methods?

What advantages does one have over the other, and what are their limitations relative to one another?

Comment: This question is too broad, and is prone to subjective answers that aren't very helpful. Please try to narrow your question, preferably thinking about a specific task that you would like to carry out.

Answer (score 2):

Most [papers](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/?term=qtl+mapping+gwas) that I've looked at distinguish between looking for genotype/trait associations in mapping populations created by experimental crosses (QTL mapping) and looking for genotype/trait associations in populations of unrelated individuals (GWAS). No distinction is made between susceptibility to disease (often referred to as a case-control GWAS) and continuous traits (all of the big studies on genetic associations with [height](https://www.nature.com/articles/ng.3097) use the term GWAS, for example).

Many of the papers in my first link use both methods, so you can take a look at them to get an idea of the advantages and limitations of each.